# Caching Doctrine results Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony2 project. My project uses database to store the data and Doctrine2 to retrieve that data.

As the data within the database has grown the queries became very slow and the whole web app takes about 2 mins to load or does not load at all.

The only way I can see my self fixing this is to cache some queries results but how can I do that. Unless there is different way of dealing with such issue.

Comment: How many SQL queries are performed? You can see this in the Symfony2 toolbar. If this is a huge number (say 100), you can reduce this number by creating functions in your repository ([random example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27907665/2257664)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to have your cache driver installed and configured in doctrine [configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) (`result_cache_driver` is important in your case). Once you have this done you can make `Doctrine` to use result cache by setting `useResultCache(true)`

```
$cachedResult = $doctrine->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->(...)
    ->useResultCache(true)
    ->(...)
```

Check [this blog post](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/caching-doctrine2-orm-results/)

**NOTE**: by default, in dev environment, result cache won't be used

**EDIT**: as you're using `DBAL` and not using `ORM` - SymfonyDoctrineBundle doesn't support this kind of cache out of the box, but you can add this support by yourself by following [this](http://www.symfony-grenoble.fr/en/331/how-to-use-doctrine-dbal-cache-with-symfony2/) detailed guide

Comment: Dzieki..I will look this up give it a go and get back to you as soon as I get some results.

Comment: Quick question will this cache per user session or it will cache globaly..?

Comment: or can I do this on top of my class responsable for querying DB `/**
 * @Cache(expires="+5 minutes", public=true)
 */`

Comment: it will be cached globally. I'm not sure if you can do this like that. You can set cache lifetime as a second parameter of useResultCache

Comment: OK thx you I think I am almost there what is the best way to test it cache is working...?

Comment: try to change something in database after your cache is populated and then check if you still get old result (remember to test it on prod environment)

Comment: I read I have to config my config.yml in order to use the above solution: http://blog.alterphp.com/2014/05/doctrine2-optimization-with-apc-cache.html

The problem is i am using Doctrine dbal nor orm therefore given solution in the article does not work, and at the same time cannot find the same solution for dbal Doctorine

Comment: At last got things working, it took a while and I also had lots of configuration to do

Comment: "NOTE: by default, in dev environment, result cache won't be used", so by default i can't debug cache usage and hit\miss for that query if i use dev mode? Can I force result cache to be used in dev mode?

Answer (score 0):

In developer mode Symfony2 creates a new cache on every query. So suppose you have many queries then it will cache all queries one by one.

This takes more time than in production mode, because in production mode the cache will only be stored once.

Comment: Yep I understand, but the problem exists in botch development and production enviroment

Comment: yopu have to clear cache to move to production mode first..!

php app/console assetic:dump