# INNER JOIN Query + WHERE doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, inner-join, query-builder

I have two tables: **contactperson** and **contactpersonlocale**.

Table **contactperson**:

- contactpersonID (Primary Key)
- tag (VARCHAR)

Table **contactpersonlocale**:

- contactpersonlocaleID (Primary Key)
- contactpersonID (Foreign Key to contactperson table)
- function (VARCHAR)
- name (VARCHAR)
- locale (VARCHAR)

In my Contactperson Entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contactpersonID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $contactpersonid;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactpersonlocale", mappedBy="contactpersonid", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $contactpersonlocale;

/**
 * Set contactpersonlocale
 *
 * @param \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactpersonlocale $contactpersonlocale
 * @return Contactpersonlocale
 */
public function setContactpersonlocale(\DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactpersonlocale $contactpersonlocale = null)
{
    $this->contactpersonlocale = $contactpersonlocale;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get contactpersonlocale
 *
 * @return \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactpersonlocale
 */
public function getContactpersonlocale()
{
    return $this->contactpersonlocale;
}
```

In my Contactpersonlocale Entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactperson
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Contactperson")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contactpersonID", referencedColumnName="contactpersonID")
 * })
 */
private $contactpersonid;
```

In my Contactperson Repository I have:

```
public function getContactpersonen($locale = 'nl')
{
    $cp = $this->createQueryBuilder('cp')
        ->select('cp')
        ->innerJoin('cp.contactpersonlocale', 'cpl')
        ->where('cpl.locale = :locale')
        ->setParameter('locale', $locale);

    return $cp->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Now when I loop through them like this:

```
$contactpersonen = $em->getRepository('MurisBundle:Contactperson')->getContactpersonen($locale);
foreach($contactpersonen as $cp)
{
    dump($cp->getcontactpersonlocale()->toArray()); die;
}
```

Then I get two personlocale objects, he doesn't take the **locale** in account (as you can see I do WHERE locale = ..). And my locale is definitely filled in .. .

[image]

What could be the problem of this?

Comment: The query correctlty extract all contractperson that have at least one locale of your...

Comment: And how can I change this?

Comment: What are your need? What do you want to extract from the db?

Comment: In my contactpersonLocale I have 2x the same conctactpersonID, but they both have a different locale. And now I would like to select all the contactpersons where locale = "nl".

Comment: I suggest you to select all the `contractPersonLocale` entity that suddisfy your criteria the navigate for the `contractPerson`entity data with and `inversedBy`relation. Let me know if this approach can be done in your case. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the WITH statement in your query:

```
$cp = $this->createQueryBuilder('cp')
        ->select('cp')
        ->innerJoin('cp.contactpersonlocale', 'cpl', 'WITH', 'cpl.locale = :locale')
        ->setParameter('locale', $locale);
```

If you want to join only Contactpersonlocale with locale = $locale.

Comment: Still giving me 2 contactpersonlocales .. He doesn't take the locale into account...

Comment: @nielsv it's working here, what query are you using? What does the profiler tell you?