# Symfony 2 cache Doctrine query results

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony2 project using Doctrine. I want to optimise the API performance by adding cache to queries.

I have looked at few options such as:

- Symfony annotation cache
- Doctrine cache
- Memcache

Not to sure with which one I should go but to me it seems like caching data at Doctrine level would be most suitable.

Saying that I would like someone to help me or guide me how to set up Doctrine cache and explain how it exactly works.

I.e I have this query:

```
class QueryFactory

    protected $connect;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connect = $connection;
    }

    private function myQuery()
    {
        return $this->connect->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('user_id')
            ->from('users', 'u')
            ->where('u.user_id = 2');
    }
}
```

How would I add a cache to this query? Is there any Doctrine library I need to inject any thing I need to `use`?

Answer (score 26):

In `doctrine` to cache queries or results you can do the following:

```
private function myQuery()
{
    return $this->connect->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('user_id')
        ->from('users', 'u')
        ->where('u.user_id = 2')
        ->getQuery()
        ->useQueryCache(true)    // here
        ->useResultCache(true);  // and here
}
```

Check  [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/caching.html#result-cache) for more info about these methods. This will make `your` cache driver working - doesn't matter what driver you are using.

To configure `Symfony` to use specific query driver you need to adjust your settings in `config.yml` - check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) to see complete list of options. What is important in your cache is (this is `apc` configuration example):

```
entity_managers:
        some_em:
            query_cache_driver: apc
            metadata_cache_driver: apc
            result_cache_driver: apc
```

You might also want to check [this](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/caching-doctrine2-orm-results/) and [this](http://blog.alterphp.com/2014/05/doctrine2-optimization-with-apc-cache.html) blog entries

Comment: and If am strictly using dbal Doctrine  is there a way..? thx

Comment: I've just ralized that you already asked identical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899297/caching-doctrine-results-symfony2/27899397#27899397