# Twig extension: database query

Tags: symfony, twig-extension

I need to do a custom filter that will convert a price to the user currency preference.
So i have a table updated everyday with the latest exchange rates.

I plan to call the filter this way {{ '200'|price }} or {{ '200'|price('USD') }}

The filter would first take the user preference from a cookie.

Then **it will query the latest exchange rate** based of the currency code and convert the actual price.

My question is, is it all right to do a database query in a twig extension (filter here).

I might have to call this filter 10 times in a page. Does that mean 10 more queries?

What better ways would you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you don't define the cache configuration for Doctrine, it means that you will send request to the database to fetch the data everytime.

You can choose between querying the exchange rates, store them in the cache yourself or using cache feature of Doctrine to do it.

[Symfony 2 cache Doctrine query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498314/symfony-2-cache-doctrine-query-results)

Both ways are better than querying the data from database directly every single time.

Comment: Thank you this is what i needed to hear.

Comment: It's enough to make static property in extension that keep exchange rates for whole request.

Comment: Hi @malcolm , I completely agree that a static property is a good solution. However, as you also pointed out, it's lifetime is a single request only so I think unless exchange rate is significant in your app and need to be updated real time (in this case you may even need a better solution than renewing it every request), I still think that put them in cache is a good solution.

Comment: @ThaiDuongTran its depend on what database you use, but question was not about store/retrieve data but how to do it in twig. Wondering why it's accepted.

Comment: @malcoml, the question is not about how to access data in twig, surely when Brieuc mentioned extension here, he know how to do it. He was just thinking about it's effiency, also as your comment is about using PHP class's static property, I am sure that there is no way the type of database you use can affect the lifetime of the PHP static property.

Answer (score 2):

Use doctrine events system, in this case `postLoad` event will be suitable. You can add prices to not mapped property in your entity, and call then in twig like: `{{ entity.prices.usd }}`

```
services:
    app.postload.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\PostLoadListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Listener class:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;



class PostLoadListener
{

protected static $currencies = [];

public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();


    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();


    if ($entity instanceof Product) {
        $price = $entity->getPrice();
        if (empty($this->currencies) {
            // get currencies from db and calculate prices
            $this->currencies = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT.....')->execute()->fetchAll();
        }

        // Calculate prices and make them as array: $prices = ['usd' => 34, 'eur` => 30 .....]

    $entity->setPrices($prices);
}
```

}

Call them in Twig:

```
{{ entity.prices[app.request.cookies.get('currency')] }}
```

Comment: That is a good idea as well. I might not be able to access the property this way entity.prices.usd since i get the currency like that {{ app.request.cookies.get('currency') }}. But anyway mentioning the doctrine events system is a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: You can: `{{ entity.prices[app.request.cookies.get('currency')] }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create class `CurrencyConverter` that will query database only once and the use its result assuming that rate is not changed during user request. Some simple service (you can inject it with DI to your Twig extension) like

```
class CurrencyConverter
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $em;

    private $rates = [];

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function convert($amount, $currency)
    {
        return $amount * $this->getRate($currency);
    }

    private function getRate($currency)
    {
        if (!isset($this->rates[$currency])) {
            $repository = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Rate');
            $this->rates[$currency] = $repository->getLatestRate($currency);
        }

        return $this->rates[$currency];
    }
}
```

This way you will have 1 database query per request per currency. If you don't have a lot of users that may be enough. MySQL most probably will load whole currency rate table to memory and will be blazing fast.

Doctrine cache may speed up more but any cache leads to additional problems and questions:

- How long should query result be in cache?
- Do I need to clear cache manually on rate update?
- Did I just got result from cache or database?

and so on.