# Best practice for using Cache Component in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony4, symfony-3.4

What is the best practice for using the Cache Component in Symfony 3?

### Simple example:

If I call `getCategoryById` (In Repository) from different places (Controller, FormType, Twig function, Listener, ...), how can I verify that the data is cached or not?

### Problem:

I can't call Cache Component in Repository and I don't want to write and duplicate the same code in every place ( ***isHint*** ... ).

### Question:

So what is the best practice? Create an intermediate cache service between all components and the Repository?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: "Two things are hard: caching, and naming things"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 2 cache Doctrine query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498314/symfony-2-cache-doctrine-query-results)