# Is it possible to use Doctrine caching results in Symfony2 custom command (cli)?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a custom Symfony2 command (extends ContainerAwareCommand) with heavy processing. It is cut in sub threads (launch another custom command) with the use of Symfony\Component\Process\Process class.

I want to improve my command by caching results from the first thread that will be used in sub threads.

Is it possible to cache results in command (cli) ?

2nd question : i have read ([Caching Doctrine results Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899297/caching-doctrine-results-symfony2/27899397#27899397)) that in dev mode, the cache is disabled. So how to test it ?

Thanks